# React Native fetch API cannot disable caching

Tags: react-native, react-redux, fetch-api

I am building android app using react native expo integrated with redux. The API is called using fetch method, but always the cached result is displayed. The server did not receive the request second time. I tried disabling cache with the following code.

```
export const mymails = (token) => {
    return fetch(
        API_URL+'?random_number='+ new Date().getTime(), {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: getHeaders(token)
    })  
    .then(response => response.json());
};

getHeaders = (token) => {
    return {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token token='+token,
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 0
    };
}
```

When I call the API through Postman client I see different result(not cached). I tried adding random number as parameter and setting cache control headers, but still returning cached result. Is there is anything else I could try.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. AFAIK, the fetch api does't automatically cache anything. Maybe the caching is happening on the API end? would you be willing to share the api endpoint so I can play with it?

Comment: I think `' Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` must be work. Can you please share API endpoint so we can check issue

Comment: you can delete this question then

Answer (score 11):

There must be a problem with how are you setting up the headers for fetching request.

**Try with following,**

You can follow the link for the same in the [Official Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/set)

```js
const mymails = (token) => {

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    myHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Token token=' + String(token));
    myHeaders.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    myHeaders.set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    myHeaders.set('Expires', '0');

    return fetch(
        API_URL + '?random_number=' + new Date().getTime(), {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: myHeaders
        })
        .then(response => response.json());
};
```