# React Native + Expo fetch cache-control

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, expo, cache-control

I am building android app using react native expo integrated with redux. The API is called using fetch method, but always the cached result is displayed. 
Cache-Control header doesn't go with request.
I've tried two types of header definition;

```
 var myHeaders = new Headers();
 myHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
 myHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 myHeaders.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

 fetch(
   "http://192.168.1.71:3000/", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: myHeaders
 })
 .then(response => console.log(response)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

and

```
 fetch("http://192.168.1.71:3000/",{
   "method": "POST",
   headers: {
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 }, cache: "no-cache",})
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

but every time request.headers in server show this:

```
{ accept: 'application/json',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  host: '192.168.1.71:3000',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.12.1' }
```

No cache-control come to server-side. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700360/react-native-fetch-api-cannot-disable-caching

Comment: Also  try without debug in expo client

Comment: Have you tried Cache-Control: no-store?