# How to clear the React Native fetch cache

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, fetch

I have a react native app that fetches a file from my server. When I change the file on the server, the app still displays the old data. I am debugging with expo.

I have:

- Cleared the DNS cache with ipconfig
- Cleared the cache on my server
- Restarted my phone
- Added the following to my fetch:

  ```
  const response = await fetch(fileName, {
   headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache" },
  ```
- Added the following to my fetch:

  ```
   const response = await fetch(fileName, {
    headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-store" },
  ```

Used `"expo start -c"`
I still get the old data. When I renamed the file on the server and in the app, the new data appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native fetch API cannot disable caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700360/react-native-fetch-api-cannot-disable-caching)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run or start again metro bundle with a **reset cache** flag.

```
npm start --reset-cache
yarn start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda works. If I did this alone. It did not work. Then I added the clear-cache to the header of the fetch and it did work. Then I took the clear-cache out and changed the file on the server and it didn't work. So it looks like, unless someone has a better solution, I need to do both things to clear the cache.

Thanks - you got me farther and I was stuck.